# Organizing Columns from a CSV file into different Variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Right now I'm importing a large .CSV file into powershell and currently just putting all the data into one variable. My question is how do I make it so I split each column into a different variable?

I'm attempting to use ForEach-Object for this, but I'm still rather new at Powershell and could use some help.

Current Code

```
$file1 = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\lin\Documents\EndpointScript.csv | select 'System Name', 'Product Version'| where 'Product Version' -eq '5.4.6.220'
$file2 = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\lin\Documents\EndpointScript.csv | select 'Product Version'| where 'Product Version' -ne '5.4.6.220'
Write-Output $file1
"Up to Date: "; $file1.Count
"Out of Date: "; $file2.Count
"Todays Date: "; Get-Date -Format g

$file1 | export-csv C:\Users\lin\Documents\AgentReport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Attemping to do something like this

```
$objectArray = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\tlines\Documents\EndpointScript.csv
$file1 | ForEach-Object {
Attemping to do something like this
```

I hope for each columns data to be in a different variable so it it's easier to do things with just one of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the columns separately without putting them in dedicated variables.
here's the csv:

```
column1;column2;column3
1a;2a;3a
1b;2b;3b
1c;2c;3c
```

Now import it and access the columns separately by using the dot notation or pipe it to select object:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Delimiter ";"

Write-Output "pipe to select-object to only retrieve a single property"
$csv | select column1 

Write-Output "access the properties with dot notation"
$csv.column1
```

Piping it to select-object will return you array of psobjects.

```
($csv | select column3 -first 1).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Dot notation will give you an array of strings.

```
$csv.column3[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

If I guess right, this should do:

```
$objectArray = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\tlines\Documents\EndpointScript.csv

$objectArray | Group-Object 'Product Version' -NoElement
```

This will return two columns:

```
Count Name
----- ----
```

Where Name contains the version numbers present.